# How to find probability with $2$ events?

Tags: probability

If you find this similar to any other question, link it in the comments please. Thanks!

Let $E$ and $F$ be two events in $S$ with $P(E) = 0.33, P(F) = 0.73, P(E ∪ F) = 0.84, P(E ∩ F) = .22$. Find $P(E ∩ F^c)$.

Please explain the math for this, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Hint:  draw a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $P(E\cap F^c)= P(E) - P(E\cap F)$